# Unit test sleep durations polly wait retry policy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, polly, retry-logic

I wanted to write a unit test to see if the execution is put to sleep for the specified duration. I have come across the `SystemClock` which is part of `Polly.Utilities`, but I'm looking for the implementation similar to Polly unit test as mentioned here [`WaitAndRetrySpecs`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/a0bc69fed1f078c469159ed36ba8426d368a7cc5/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/WaitAndRetrySpecs.cs#L325), which looks like this

```
 [Fact]
 public void Should_sleep_for_the_specified_duration_each_retry_when_specified_exception_thrown_same_number_of_times_as_there_are_sleep_durations()
 {
      var totalTimeSlept = 0;

      var policy = Policy
            .Handle<DivideByZeroException>()
            .WaitAndRetry(new[]
            {
               1.Seconds(),
               2.Seconds(),
               3.Seconds()
            });

      SystemClock.Sleep = span => totalTimeSlept += span.Seconds;

      policy.RaiseException<DivideByZeroException>(3);

      totalTimeSlept.Should()
                      .Be(1 + 2 + 3);
  }
```

Currently my policy looks like

```
var customPolicy = Policy
                     .Handle<SqlException>(x => IsTransientError(x))
                     .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                      3,
                      (retryAttempt) => getSleepDurationByRetryAtempt(retryAttempt)
                     );
```

I want to test overall time slept for policy. For each retry attempts [1,2,3] sleep durations are [1,2,3].
After all 3 retries the total sleep duration should be 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. This test very similar to Polly specs mentioned in the link above.

**Question:** How do I write the unit test for the customPolicy to test the total sleep duration similar to the polly specs. I want to see a implementation or directions to write the unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by utilizing the `onRetry` function.

To make it simple let me define the `IsTransientError` and `GetSleepDurationByRetryAttempt` methods like this:

```cs
public TimeSpan GetSleepDurationByRetryAttempt(int attempt) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(attempt);
public bool IsTransientError(SqlException ex) => true;
```

BTW you can shorten your policy definition by avoiding (unnecessary) anonymous lambdas:

```
var customPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<SqlException>(IsTransientError)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, GetSleepDurationByRetryAttempt)
```

So, back to the onRetry. There is [an overload](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/d95959fe1449407603c8605282fbba97041fd026/src/Polly/Retry/AsyncRetrySyntax.cs#L411) which have the following signature: `Action<Exception, TimeSpan, Context>`. Here the second parameter is the sleep duration.

All we need to do is to provide a function here, which accumulates the sleep durations.

```cs
var totalSleepDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
...
onRetry: (ex, duration, ctx) => { totalSleepDuration = totalSleepDuration.Add(duration); }
```

Let's put all these together:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task GivenACustomSleepDurationProvider_WhenIUseItInARetryPolicy_ThenTheAccumulatedDurationIsAsExpected()
{
    //Arrange
    var totalSleepDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var customPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<SqlException>(IsTransientError)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, GetSleepDurationByRetryAttempt,
            onRetry: (ex, duration, ctx) => { totalSleepDuration = totalSleepDuration.Add(duration); }
        );

    //Act
    Func<Task> actionWithRetry = async() => await customPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => throw new SqlException());
    
    //Assert
    _ = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<SqlException>(actionWithRetry);
    Assert.Equal(6, totalSleepDuration.Seconds);
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1**: Reduce delays and introduce theory

Depending on your requirements it might make sense to run this same test case with different parameters. That's where `Theory` and `InlineData` can help you:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(3, 600)]
[InlineData(4, 1000)]
[InlineData(5, 1500)]
public async Task GivenACustomSleepDurationProvider_WhenIUseItInARetryPolicy_ThenTheAccumulatedDurationIsAsExpected(int retryCount, int expectedTotalSleepInMs)
{
    //Arrange
    var totalSleepDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var customPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<SqlException>(IsTransientError)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount, GetSleepDurationByRetryAttempt,
            onRetry: (ex, duration, ctx) => { totalSleepDuration = totalSleepDuration.Add(duration); }
        );

    //Act
    Func<Task> actionWithRetry = async () => await customPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => throw new SqlException());

    //Assert
    _ = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<SqlException>(actionWithRetry);
    Assert.Equal(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(expectedTotalSleepInMs), totalSleepDuration);
}

public static TimeSpan GetSleepDurationByRetryAttempt(int attempt) => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(attempt * 100);
```

---

**UPDATE #2**: Passing the TimeSpan via the `Context`

In order to make the transfer and retrieval of the `TimeSpan` [a bit more type-safe](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Keys-And-Context-Data#example-varying-the-ilogger-used-within-an-onretry-delegate) we can create two extension methods for this:

```cs
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    private const string Accumulator = "DurationAccumulator";

    public static Context SetAccumulator(this Context context, TimeSpan durationAccumulator)
    {
        context[Accumulator] = durationAccumulator;
        return context;
    }

    public static TimeSpan? GetAccumulator(this Context context)
    {
        if (!context.TryGetValue(Accumulator, out var ts))
            return null;

        if (ts is TimeSpan accumulator) 
            return accumulator;

        return null;
    }
}
```

We can also extract the Policy creation logic:

```cs
private AsyncPolicy GetCustomPolicy(int retryCount)
    => Policy
        .Handle<SqlException>(IsTransientError)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount, GetSleepDurationByRetryAttempt,
            onRetry: (ex, duration, ctx) =>
            {
                var totalSleepDuration = ctx.GetAccumulator();
                if (!totalSleepDuration.HasValue) return;
                totalSleepDuration = totalSleepDuration.Value.Add(duration);
                ctx.SetAccumulator(totalSleepDuration.Value);
            });
```

Now let's put all these together (once again):

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(3, 600)]
[InlineData(4, 1000)]
[InlineData(5, 1500)]
public async Task GivenACustomSleepDurationProvider_WhenIUseItInARetryPolicy_ThenTheAccumulatedDurationIsAsExpected(
        int retryCount, int expectedTotalSleepInMs)
{
    //Arrange
    var totalSleepDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var customPolicy = GetCustomPolicy(retryCount);
    var context = new Context().SetAccumulator(totalSleepDuration);

    //Act
    Func<Task> actionWithRetry = async () => await customPolicy.ExecuteAsync(ctx => throw new SqlException(), context);

    //Assert
    _ = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<SqlException>(actionWithRetry);
    var accumulator = context.GetAccumulator();
    Assert.NotNull(accumulator);
    Assert.Equal(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(expectedTotalSleepInMs), accumulator.Value);
}
```

Comment: It makes sense, I guess only change I might think of is adding totalSleepDuration to context and access it in the overload you mentioned because my policy is defined in a different class(kinda factory) not in the unit test method. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @user14530157 I've updated to answer to pass the `totalSleepDuration` via the `Context`. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

The test is not working because you are using WaitAndRetryAsync instead of WaitAndRetry.  I had a similar problem and fixed by using

```
 SystemClock.SleepAsync = (s, cts) =>
        {
            totalTimeSlept += s.Seconds;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
```